# `np.concatenate` a numpy array with a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

A dataset contains numerical and categorial variables, and I split then into two parts:

```
cont_data = data[cont_variables].values
disc_data = data[disc_variables].values
```

Then I use `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` to encode the categorical data, and then I tried to merge the coded categorical data with the numerical data:

```
np.concatenate((cont_data, disc_data_coded), axis=1)
```

But the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

I ensured that the number of dimensions are equal:

```
print(cont_data.shape)        # (24000, 35)
print(disc_data_coded.shape)  # (24000, 26)
```

Finally, I found that `cont_data` is a `numpy array` while

```
>>> disc_data_coded
<24000x26 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 312000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I changed the parameter `sparse` in `OneHotEncoder`to be `False`, everything is OK. 
But the question is, how can I merge a `numpy array` with a `sparse matrix` directly, without setting `sparse=False`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sparse matrices are not subclasses of numpy arrays; so `numpy` methods often don't work.  Use sparse functions instead, such as `sparse.vstack` and `sparse.hstack`. But all inputs then have to be sparse.

Or make the sparse matrix dense first, with `.toarray()`, and use `np.concatenate`.

Do you want the result to sparse or dense?

```
In [32]: sparse.vstack((sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(10)),sparse.csr_matrix(np.on
    ...: es((3,10)))))
Out[32]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 39 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [33]: np.concatenate((sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(10)).A,np.ones((3,10))))
Out[33]: 
array([[0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: just for supplementary, here `sparse` is a sub-module from `scipy`. To run the code above, just add: `from scipy import sparse`.