# Train `sklearn` ML model with scipy sparse matrix and numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, concatenation

Just to explain some things more about my use case, `A` is a sparse matrix with tf-idf values and `B` is an array with some additional features of my data.

I have already splitted to training and test sets so `A` and `B` in my example are only about the training set. I (want to) do the same for the test set after this code.

I want to concatenate these matrices/arrays because then I want to pass them to a `sklearn` ML model to train it and I do not think that I can pass them separately.

So I tried to do this:

```
C = np.concatenate((A, B.T), axis=1)
```

where A is a `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` and B is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

However, when I try to do this then I get the following error:

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Also, I do not think that the idea of [`np.concatenate` a numpy array with a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420274/np-concatenate-a-numpy-array-with-a-sparse-matrix) is very good in my case because

1. it is basically impossible to covert my sparse array `A` to a dense array because it is too big
2. I will lose **(or not actually??)** information if I convert my fully dense array `B` to a sparse array

What is the best way to pass to an `sklearn` ML model a sparse and a fully dense array concatenated by rows?

Comment: Do you want the result to be an array?  You can convert your sparse matrix to an array using `A.A`

Comment: @user3483203, hm I see your point. My sparse matrix is too big to convert it to an array. Ideally I would like to to have as an output a "hybrid" array where its one part is a sparse matrix and the other one an array.

Comment: That isn't really possible with `numpy`.  What is your final use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`np.concatenate\` a numpy array with a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49420274/np-concatenate-a-numpy-array-with-a-sparse-matrix)

Comment: @user3483203, basically the sparse matrix are tf-idf data and the array is some additional features. I want to have one final concatenated array so that I can pass it to a ML model (e.g. random forest) and train it etc. I think that you cannot pass multiple arrays (of different kinds) as training sets in `sklearn`?

Comment: OK, so I assume you are chunking your sparse array at some point.  Rather than concatenate the entire thing, you could concatenate only the chunks of the array and the sparse matrix at a time.

Comment: @user3483203, hm I am not sure what you mean. Where/When exactly will I concatenate them at a time? I am not really chunking sparse array. I just split to training and test set at the very beginning of my application.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` has its own `vstack` and `hstack`.  These convert all inputs to `coo` sparse format, and make a new `coo` matrix from the combined data/row/col attributes.  `np.array(a_sparse_matrix)` does not create a valid `ndarray`.  `a_sparse_matrix.toarray()` is the proper converter.

Comment: @hpaulj, I am not sure how your comment answers my points (1) and (2) above towards the end of my post. Have you read them? What is your specific answer to each one of them?

Comment: My comment addresses the 0d error.

Comment: @hpaulj, cool, this is already answered by your post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420566/9024698.

Comment: @hpaulj, so then two questions: 1) We definitely cannot then have a "hybrid" matrix which has a sparse matrix and a numpy array concatenated in it?, 2) If you see my points above, I say that (1) is impossible because my sparse matrix is too big. What about (2)? Do I lose information if I convert a fully dense array to a sparse matrix or not?

Comment: however @hpaulj I did not see your answers here ;)

Answer (score 6):

1. You can use [`hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html) from scipy. `hstack` will convert both matrices to scipy [`coo_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html), merge them and return a coo_matrix by default.
2. No information is lost when converting dense array to sparse. Sparse matrices are just compact data storage format. Also, unless to specify a value for argument `dtype` of `hstack` everything is [upcasted](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/14bcde64c822a3d8d66c1dbde812b5336b2c83a2/scipy/sparse/sputils.py#L21). So, there is no possibility of data loss there as well.

**Further**, if you plan to use Logistic Regression from sklearn, sparse matrices must be in **csr** format for `fit` method to work.

The following code should work for your use-case

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack

X = hstack((A, B), format='csr')
```