# Covert to sparse matrix - TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('0'),)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to do this:

```
  features = csr_matrix(features)
```

where `features` is a `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` and looks like that:

```
[[51 1]
 [49 2]
 [47 2]
 ...
 [2 6]
 [20 2]
 [16 1]]
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)
```

What is this error about and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using sparse with data like this?  I don't see a lot of zeros.  What exactly is this `features` object (array?) supposed to represent?

Comment: @hpaulj, thank you for your questions. I use sparse data because of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362560/train-sklearn-ml-model-with-scipy-sparse-matrix-and-numpy-array if it makes sense. `features` are simply some (dense) features along with the tf-idf sparse features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may redefine your numpy array specifying the `dtype`explicitly

```
features = np.array(features, dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
csr_matrix(features.astype(np.float))
```

If this has an error, then you have things that aren't numbers in your features.